# Select field and retrieve corresponding id

Tags: php, forms, select

I'm searching a way to retrieve an ID corresponding to a 'select' without execute any other query when I select an item from Database:

I use the select item in a form.

Here is the way I select some names from a table from Database:

```
    $sql = "SELECT ID, Name,Surname FROM Table;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$result) die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());
    $la = "<SELECT name='names'>";
    $la .= "<OPTION selected='selected' disabled='disabled' >Choose a name</OPTION>";

    while(list($id, $name) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $selectnames .= "<OPTION >$name</OPTION>";
    }
    $selectnames .= "</SELECT>";
```

I want to know the ID corresponding to the '$selectnames' I select from a form,

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what it is you want. Can you try to be a little clearer/show examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `value` of the option to `$id`:

```
while(list($id, $name) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $selectnames .= "<OPTION value='$id'>$name</OPTION>";
}
```

And then when the form is posted you can check `$_POST['names']` to get the ID. As you might have noticed, if you don't specify the `value` then `$_POST['name']` will contain the `$name` value rather than the `$id` value.